# Como substituir o CheckBox por uma String

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Preciso exibir **"Ativo"** ou **"Inativo"** na coluna Situação do *DataGridView*, como fazer ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa Coluna "Situação" é do tipo Booleano: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o Código onde preencho o *DataGridView*:

```
private void PreencherDataGridView()
        {
            try
            {
                ConvenioModel convenio = new ConvenioModel();
                convenio.STATUS = rdbFiltroAtivo.Checked;
                dgvConvenio.DataSource = ConvenioNegocio.ListarConvenioMedico(convenio);

                dgvConvenio.Columns["ID_CONVENIO_MEDICO"].Visible = false;                    
                dgvConvenio.Columns["CNPJ"].Width = 80;
                dgvConvenio.Columns["RAZAO_SOCIAL"].Width = 150;
                dgvConvenio.Columns["NM_FANTASIA"].Width = 150;
                dgvConvenio.Columns["DT_CADASTRO"].Width = 50;
                dgvConvenio.Columns["DT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO"].Width = 50;
                dgvConvenio.Columns["STATUS"].Width = 30;

                dgvConvenio.Columns["RAZAO_SOCIAL"].HeaderText = "RAZÃO SOCIAL";
                dgvConvenio.Columns["NM_FANTASIA"].HeaderText = "NOME FANTASIA";
                dgvConvenio.Columns["DT_CADASTRO"].HeaderText = "DT CADASTRO";
                dgvConvenio.Columns["DT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO"].HeaderText = "ATUALIZAÇÃO EM";
                dgvConvenio.Columns["STATUS"].HeaderText = "SITUAÇÃO";

                dgvConvenio.Columns["CNPJ"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
                dgvConvenio.Columns["DT_CADASTRO"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                dgvConvenio.Columns["DT_ULT_ATUALIZACAO"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                dgvConvenio.Columns["CNPJ"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "00.000.000/0000-00";


                dgvConvenio.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Você pode mudar o tipo da coluna para texto e o tipo do dado (retornado em `ConvenioNegocio.ListarConvenioMedico`) para `string`.

Comment: Aliás, capturar uma exceção apenas para lançar uma nova com a mesma mensagem não faz o mínimo sentido. Dessa forma, você perde a origem do problema e ainda obriga o runtime a fazer o lançamento desnecessário de uma exceção.

Comment: uma opção é criar uma propriedade no model pra representar isso: `public string StatusNome { {get{ return this.Status ? "Ativo" : "Inativo"; } }`

Comment: É uma opção bem melhor, aliás. Só uma nota: poderia ser escrito assim: `public string StatusNome => Status ? "Ativo" : "Inativo"`

Comment: @LINQ obrigado pela observação alterei meu código e deixei somente o throw;, catch{ throw; }.

Comment: pode até tirar o try catch... a exceção irá propagar da mesma forma...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou supor que seu objeto carregado no `DataGridView` seja o `ConvenioNegocio`. Então, você cria uma propriedade somente leitura que vai exibir o valor como `string`:

```
public class ConvenioNegocio
{
    //...outras propriedades
    public bool Status {get;set;}
    public string Situacao => Status ? "Ativo" : "Inativo;
}
```

Agora você terá uma coluna a mais do DataGridView para representar a propriedade `Situacao`, basta ocultar a `STATUS`:

```
 dgvConvenio.Columns["STATUS"].Visible = false;

 dgvConvenio.Columns["SITUACAO"].HeaderText = "Situação";
```

> Ps. Não sei como você está gerando as colunas, então é só um exemplo.